# tombstone warnings with data loaded using sstableloader

Tags: cassandra

I am loading the data from one of my cassandra table to a new table with modified partition key. As a first step I took the dump of current table into a csv file.
Afterwards I used CQLSSTableWriter to generate sstables as below.

```
// Prepare SSTable writer 
CQLSSTableWriter.Builder builder = CQLSSTableWriter.builder();
// set output directory 
builder.inDirectory(outputDir)
   // set target schema 
   .forTable(SCHEMA)
   // set CQL statement to put data 
   .using(INSERT_STMT)
   // set partitioner if needed 
   // default is Murmur3Partitioner so set if you use different one. 
   .withPartitioner(new Murmur3Partitioner());
CQLSSTableWriter writer = builder.build();

// ...snip... 

while ((line = csvReader.read()) != null)
{
        writer.addRow(DATE_FORMAT.parse(line.get(0)),
               UUID.fromString(line.get(1)),
               line.get(2),
               line.get(3),
               line.get(4),
               Long.parseLong(line.get(5)),
               line.get(6));
}
writer.close();
```

The problem arises when my csv/existing table has some null values.

After loading the sstables in cassandra, I see lot of warnings related to tombstones. Is there any way I can get rid of the tombstones?

Answer (score 0):

In some cases setting a column to NULL is the same as writing a tombstone.

Make sure to set these high enough in cassandra.yaml file, so the queries do not fail, but not so high that you experience GC issues. This modification will need to be tuned incrementally and assessed.

```
Tombstone_warn_threshold
Tombstone_failure_threshold
```

Now you should Run major compaction (STCS, LCS for Cassandra 2.2+) or reset levels for all SSTables (LCS Cassandra<2.2) of the affected table.

In case you have to go with reset then you can take help of below link:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsSSTableLevelReset.html

Comment: Compaction is one way. Is there any way where I can avoid inserting the nulls.